# This code fails, but why? Returning memory address of an integer pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

```
#include<cstdio>

int *f1(){

    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    return arr;
}


int main(){

    printf("%d", *(f1()+3));
    // printf("%d", f1()[3]);

    return 0;

}
```

The code above gives `Segmentation fault` at runtime. But I don't understand why. I am creating an integer array in my `f1()` function and filling it with values. Then returning the address of that array(address of the first element). So, I expect to be able to reach it from main. However, apparently, I cannot do it.

Comment: As `arr` is a local variable it’s on the stack - once the function returns that is no longer available and attempting to access it is doomed. Use `malloc` Maybe?

Comment: @barny yes, using `malloc` gave the desired result. So, I don't have much information about stack and heap, but from this example, is using `malloc` allocates memory in heap instead of stack and so it is why it works with malloc?

Comment: Yes - the catch is that you have to remember to `free` the allocation when you no longer need it, otherwise memory usage will keep increasing, an effect usually referred as a memory leak. A better design would almost always be to pass a pointer into the function rather than it calling malloc and expecting the free to be done elsewhere.

Comment: @barny yes, I also tried by passing the array and it seems a better idea too. The memory gets cleaned automatically after the program executes and finishes right?

Comment: Yes all memory is released when your program exits - but don’t use that as a reason not to correctly free every malloc!

Comment: @barny OK, thanks for the all.